# Boost link error using Conan find_package

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, cmake, conan

I'm trying to build a simple program using boost via conan's cmake_find_package generator.
I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and get the following error during the linking:

> LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_78.lib'

The installed boost conan package includes only `libboost_filesystem.lib`. How do I link against this library instead of `libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_78.lib`?
Is there another, correct way of using conan boost?

conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
boost/1.78.0

[generators]
cmake_find_package
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(TestProject)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

conan configuration:

```
[settings]
os=Windows
os_build=Windows
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
compiler=Visual Studio
compiler.version=16
compiler.runtime=MT
build_type=Release
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]
```

Comment: `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)`... I guarantee you aren't using CMake 2.8.12. Never set this to a lower version than you actually test your build on.

Comment: Indeed, I'm using the VS19 provoded cmake, whis is 3.20 or above, if I'm not mistaken. Nevertheless, it doesn't matter for this specific error.

Comment: It will matter for other errors, though, which is why I left it as a comment rather than posting it as an answer.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - that's true for the `cmake` generator, but not for the `cmake_find_package` generator, which is being used here.

Comment: @AlexReinking: Thanks, didn't know that specific.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)
```

solved this for me.